# SQL statement to count corresponding entries

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem to count corresponding contact, sites and devis of a client in my database.

My tables are :

```
TABLE Devis 
idDevis (PK)
idSiteClient (FK)
```

```
TABLE SiteClient
idSiteClient (PK)
idClient (FK)
```

```
 TABLE Client
    idClient (PK)
```

```
 TABLE Contact
    idContact (PK)
    idClient (FK)
```

My current statement is

```
$requete = myPDO::getInstance()->prepare(<<<SQL
        SELECT COUNT(sc.idSiteClient), COUNT(dvs.idDevis), COUNT(ct.idContact)
        FROM SiteClient sc, Devis dvs, Client clt, Contact ct
        WHERE dvs.idSiteClient = sc.idSiteClient
        AND sc.idClient = clt.idClient
        AND clt.idClient = ct.idClient
        AND clt.idClient = :id
SQL
);

    $requete->execute(array(":id" => $id));
```

But it gives me 15, 15, 15 which is wrong, I should have 5 Site, 2 Devis and 5 contact

thanks for help

Comment: You are counting the number of rows from the JOIN here. (Remove the COUNT and execute the same select, and see what you get.)

Comment: [{"idSiteClient":"1","idDevis":"14","idContact":"3"}] don't get where it comes from

Comment: Just did, gave 2, 3, 5

Comment: Please provide more information.  Show the data in these tables for this client? or describe the schema relationships and constraints

Comment: Already got answer, but i gave all FK and PK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this:

```
WITH 
  clt1 AS (SELECT * FROM Client clt WHERE clt.idClient = :id),
  ct1 AS (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, ct.* FROM Contact ct JOIN clt1 ON clt1.idClient = ct.idClient),
  sc1 AS (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, sc.* FROM SiteClient sc JOIN clt1 ON clt1.idClient = sc.idClient),
  dvs1 AS (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, dvs.* FROM Devis dvs JOIN sc1 ON sc1.idSiteClient = dvs.idSiteClient)
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(sc1.cnt, 0), NVL(dvs1.cnt, 0), NVL(ct1.cnt, 0)
FROM sc1, dvs1, ct1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Distinct

```
   SELECT COUNT(distinct sc.idSiteClient), 
       COUNT(distinct  dvs.idDevis), COUNT(distinct ct.idContact)
    FROM SiteClient sc, Devis dvs, Client clt, Contact ct
    WHERE dvs.idSiteClient = sc.idSiteClient
    AND sc.idClient = clt.idClient
    AND clt.idClient = ct.idClient
    AND clt.idClient = :id
```

Comment: it will not work correctly e. g. when there are no dvs (you will get 0,0,0)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one

```
SELECT 
cl.idClient, 
sc.SiteNo, 
con.ContactNo,
dev.DevisNo

FROM Client cl
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(distinct idClient) AS SiteNo, idClient, idSiteClient FROM SiteClient GROUP BY idClient, idSiteClient) sc ON  cl.idClient = st.idClient
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS ContactNo, idClient FROM Contact GROUP BY idClient) con ON  cl.idClient = con.idClient
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS DevisNo, idSiteClient FROM Devis GROUP BY idSiteClient) dev ON  sc.idSiteClient = dev.idSiteClient
WHERE 
cl.idClient = :id
```

Comment: there is just a problem on the 3rd LEFT JOIN because Client is not directly related to Devis, there is SiteClient between both

Comment: than you need to correct your question and give me more details of table design